# update not working in SQLite Database in Android Application

Tags: android, sqlite, insert-update

I am working on a android project. In which I have used `SMS Scheduling`. For that I have created SQLite Database. In database created SMSTABLE. In SMSTABLE, there is a column name "status". Which defines whether it is draft message, scheduled,sent or unsent message. `For draft status = 0, for scheduled status = 1, for sent status = 2,for unsent status = 3`. By default status value is set to 1. When I update status for draft it doesn't work(update into db).

Following are some parts of my code of `DBHepler Class`:

```
private final String DATABASE_CREATE_SMS_TABLE = "create table " + DATABASE_SMS_TABLE
        + " ("
        + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_MESSAGE + " text, "
        + KEY_DATE + " text, "
        + KEY_START_TIME_MILLIS + " long, "
        + KEY_END_TIME_MILLIS + " long, "
        + KEY_MSG_PARTS + " integer default 0, "
        + KEY_STATUS + " integer default 1, "
        + KEY_REPEAT_MODE + " integer, "
        + KEY_REPEAT_STRING + " text);";


 /***
 * @param message
 * @param date
 * @param parts        //* @param timeInMilis
 * @param repeatMode
// * @param repeatString
 * @return smsId for the newly scheduled SMS
 * @detail Schedules a new SMS using the details passed as parameters
 */
public long scheduleSms(String message, String date, int parts, long startTimeInMilis, long endTimeInMilis, int repeatMode) {
    ContentValues addValues = new ContentValues();

    addValues.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);
    addValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    // addValues.put(KEY_TIME_MILLIS, timeInMilis);
    addValues.put(KEY_START_TIME_MILLIS, startTimeInMilis);
    addValues.put(KEY_END_TIME_MILLIS, endTimeInMilis);
    addValues.put(KEY_MSG_PARTS, parts);
    addValues.put(KEY_REPEAT_MODE, repeatMode);
 //   addValues.put(KEY_REPEAT_STRING, repeatString);

    return db.insert(DATABASE_SMS_TABLE, null, addValues);
}

/***
 * @param smsId
 * @detail Sets an SMS as Draft
 */
public void setAsDraft(long smsId) {
    setStatus(smsId, Constants.SMS_STATUS_DRAFT);
}


/***
 * @param smsId
 * @param status
 * @detail Sets a particular status for an SMS. Status is passed as parameter
 */
public void setStatus(long smsId, int status) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_STATUS, status);

    db.update(DATABASE_SMS_TABLE, cv, KEY_ID + "=" + smsId, null);
}
```

Following is my code where I call to update draft status :

```
 dbHelper.open();
                boolean isDraft = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < messagesList.size(); i++) {
                    parts = smsManager.divideMessage(messagesList.get(i).getMessage());
                    long smsId = dbHelper.scheduleSms(messagesList.get(i).getMessage(), dateString, parts.size(), startTime, endTime, defaultRepeatMode);
                    dbHelper.setAsDraft(smsId);
                    isDraft = true;
                }
```

Comment: where/ how did you declare "db"? and in what way does the update not work? crash? nothing happens?

Comment: whats the value of Constants.SMS_STATUS_DRAFT

Comment: and why is smsId a long... in your scheme the smsId is defined as integer

Comment: @silly - AFAIK the range of "INTEGER" in SQLite is more like the range of  "long" in Java.

Comment: @0X0nosugar nothing happens.

Comment: @silly Constants.SMS_STATUS_DRAFT = 0

Comment: did the insert work? (try to log the value of smsId)

Comment: @0X0nosugar yes I debug it. Insert is working.

Comment: just to be on the safe side: could you write 'KEY_ID + **" = "** + smsId' instead of 'KEY_ID + "=" + smsId' ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98147/discussion-between-mobile-tech-and-0x0nosugar).

Comment: Are you sure your `smsId` inside `setStatus` is as you expected and not -1 or something? I'd suggest debugging after the `update` call, then just looking at the query generated, grab your db from the device/emulator, open in http://sqlitebrowser.org/ and try manually running the same query.. Usually helps. Also sqlitebrowser useful for browsing the schema and the data of the db and seeing what's in those tables - easier to spot an error that way.

Comment: try `db.update(DATABASE_SMS_TABLE, cv, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(smsId)});`